# Passing function as argument removes correct reference to self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I have this bit of code using `concurrent.futures` in python 3.6:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS_ALLOWED) as executor:
        for file in executor.map(self.upload_chunked_part, chunk_list):
            total = total + file
            elapsed_time = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
            current_speed = round(total / (elapsed_time * 1024 * 1024), 2)
            progress_bar("Uploading %s at %sMB/s" %
                         (media.name, current_speed), total, size)

// Each loop returns "Login required to API"
```

`self.upload_chunked_part` refers to a method attached to the class that this bit of code is in. When the method is called by `futures`, the instance of `self` that shows up in the called code is not the same as the one that shows up if I just call the method normally:

```
self.upload_chunked_part(chunk) // Returns "Successful"
```

I hope I've explained that problem well enough. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You're using a process pool and processes don't share memory. The instances can't be the same therefore. However I'd expect that they are duplicated, what's the exact problem or the difference that you are facing?

Comment: You are using `multiprocessing`, essentially, and it doesn't share state, it *copies* data.

Comment: stewart: That means all those global variables you're attempting to use in the method don't exist in the other processes' address space (or if they do, they'll all have only the initial values that were assigned to them when the main script was started). One possible workaround that would be to pass them all as arguments to the called method (or get rid of them entirely if they aren't constants like, say, `MAX_WORKERS_ALLOWED`).

Comment: Okay, good to know. How do I pass in more variables to the method?